# How to prevent bootbox modal from closing by clicking on a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootbox

I add a button in the footer and I don't want that the modal close when I click on it. I tried preventDefault but it doesn't work..

```
dialog.find('.modal-footer').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Display</button>')
```

I use bootbox.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the code of the entire modal?

Comment: The button in `modal-footer` only closes the modal because `data-dismiss="modal"` is being applied. We'll need to see more of your code to understand why any button trigger is closing the modal.

Comment: I made a mistake, I use bootbox and not boostrap

Comment: I edited the topic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. I added the button like this.

```
buttons: {            
        success: {
            label: "Display",
            className: "btn-primary",
            callback: function () {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

> return false

in callback prevent the closing.

Thank you.